# Searching Record in mongodb using php

Tags: mongodb, search, find

I am getting the records from collections in following format using find() function of mongodb

```
Array
(
    [_id] => MongoId Object
        (
            [$id] => 52a9b86578e9288a378b4567
        )

[0] => Array
    (
        [senderID] => 1
        [followingID] => 15
        [type] => TW
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [senderID] => 1
        [followingID] => 16
        [type] => TW
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [senderID] => 1
        [followingID] => 17
        [type] => TW
    )

 [3] => Array
    (
        [senderID] => 2
        [followingID] => 17
        [type] => TW
    )
```

)

Now I want all the records whose senderID is 2. I have tried by passing array in find function

```
$myarray("senderID"=> 1)
$collection->find($myarray)
```

but it will not get the correct record.

Comment: Can you pass through a structure similar to mongo native commands like this? db.collectionsname.find( { "senderID": {2} } )

Comment: Thanks buddy i got it actually there are one more key values is coming in the array which diffrent from all other key values so i just removed it and then tried .. got a success